# Using curl to upload POST data with files @ in postfields

Tags: php, curl, post, file-upload

I would like to use cURL to not only send data parameters in HTTP POST but to also upload files with specific name. How should I go about doing that ?

the api also gives example of how to do the curl command

```
curl -k -F file=@/path/to/file.txt -F apiId={apiId} -F apiSecretId={apiSecretId} https:\/\/fa2a.ninjastream.to\/api\/file\/upload?expires=1596028934&signature=132d1332996262809c7cc2dcd6376c483d6521dc7c273f9275ee1acb53e0b072
```

so this is the function i have

```
function uploadfileandgetlink($uploadurl){
  
          $ch = curl_init();

          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadurl);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  
  
 
          $post = array(
            
            
              'file'  => '@beztam.mp4',
              'apiId' => 'sdfg',
              'apiSecretId' => 'dsfg'
          );
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

          echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
          if (curl_errno($ch)) {
              echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
          }
          curl_close($ch);
```

the response i get is {"status":"error","message":"No file inputted"}

**Update : fixed by replacing string @beztam.mp4 to
`curl_file_create(__DIR__ .'/beztam.mp4')`**

Comment: Have you looked at [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thanks so much i tried it worked like a charm

Comment: Excellent! Glad that worked - good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: Excellent! Glad that worked - good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('beztam.mp4'); 
$post = array(
            
            
              'file'  => rawurlencode($fileContent),
              'apiId' => 'sdfg',
              'apiSecretId' => 'dsfg'
          );
```

Comment: did not work but i posted the solution thanks so much for putting the time to help